# Resize first partition on MacBook Pro M2, having two partitions with each MacOSX installed

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition

I'm having a MacBook Pro with M2 chip from the company I work for. It is allowed to use the device with a separate OS installed on it. That's why I currently have two partitions, each with another version of MacOSX installed (one for the company and one for my private purposes).

I made the mistake to give the first partition (the company OS partition) too less space (100GB) and I need to extend it to have more. Else I cannot install required updates and so on.

The problem is, that by shrinking the second partition, free space is added AFTER it. But to extend the first partition, it would be necessary to move the shrinked partition to the end, to have the free space BEFORE it.

Is this somehow possible? I remember, that with GParted (on a "normal" PC) it was possible to move partitions around (which took more time, of course).

Can this be done on this ARM device? Do you know a tool? Is it probably possible with a Ubuntu Linux on an USB stick?

Thanks for your help!

[image: Image showing Mac OSX' Disk Utility which the current state of the partitions]

Answer (score 0):

Intel Macs had an EFI (later referred to as an UEFI) which allowed booting GParted and Linux. Apple Silicon Macs do not have this and therefore cannot boot GParted and almost all Linux.

You can use the Disk Utility to clone APFS containers. For example, you could do the following.

1. Clone the second APFS partition to an external drive.
2. Remove the second APFS partition.
3. Increase the size of the first APFS partition and leave the remaining space to a second APFS partition.
4. Clone back to the second APFS partition from the external drive.

Of course, you should backup everything before cloning. Once backed up, this leaves the question of why not do the following?

1. Remove the second APFS partition.
2. Increase the size of the first APFS partition and leave the remaining space to a second APFS partition.
3. Install macOS to the second APFS partition.
4. Restore the second APFS partition from the backup.

Comment: Can you please get more into detail? The first solution doesn't seem to work for me, there is some "seal" problem and I have a Volume containing two partitions "Untitled" and "Untitled - Data". Both have the exact same size (the sum exceeds the total size).


How can I create a backup that is restorable into a new partition?